# AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal true

Tags: api, rest, postman-testcase

"Below code through the error:"

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.inStock).to.eql(true);
});
```

Comment: [
    {
        "id": 4643,
        "category": "coffee",
        "name": "Starbucks Coffee Variety Pack, 100% Arabica",
        "inStock": true
    },
    {
        "id": 4646,
        "category": "coffee",
        "name": "Ethical Bean Medium Dark Roast, Espresso",
        "inStock": true
    },
    {
        "id": 4641,
        "category": "coffee",
        "name": "Don Francisco Colombia Supremo Medium Roast",
        "inStock": true
    }
]

Comment: Can you print the value of jsonData.

Comment: Check the HTTP request & response, maybe not the same data is served. Or do you send the complete array? If so, the `jsonData[1].inStock` maybe.